# How to find font name in Fireworks when font not installed

Tags: fonts, adobe-fireworks

I have inherited a design in a Fireworks file which I'm turning into a web page.  I've never used Fireworks but it seems to be similar (user-interface-wise) to Photoshop so it's going okay.  However, there are a number of fonts used in the design which I don't have installed on my PC.  When I open the file in Fireworks it asks if I want to 'Replace fonts' or 'Maintain appearance'.  Since I need to see the graphics accurately I select 'Maintain appearance'.  However, now when I select any of the text it doesn't tell me what font it's trying to use (I'm not trying to edit the text and I realise I couldn't without the font being installed on my machine, but I just need to know what font it is).

In Photoshop when you select a font that's not installed on your machine, it asks if you'd like to replace {name of font} with another font.  So you can easily tell what the original font is even if you can't edit it without changing to a font you have installed.

How would I do this in Fireworks?  I just need to know what text is in what font so I can code up the web page accurately.

Thanks for any pointers folks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the only way to see which fonts are used, is to use "Replace fonts", note the missing ones and close the file without saving. 
Search them, download/buy/install them and you are done.

I'm not aware of another way to do it. :/

Comment: Thats good enough for me :) Displays the font i need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an easier/better way, but you could make screenshots of the lines of text in those fonts (and save those in separate images) and use a font identification site (such as **[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)**). If that doesn't help you can always upload it here and ask this community. ;)

Comment: Thanks.  To do that for each different snippet of text across the whole site is going to be extremely painful though, so I don't think it's really an option.  I think 'guessing' is my best bet at the moment - I can kind of tell what font is what but I don't particularly like guess-work and thought there must be an easier way like there is in Photoshop.

Comment: Come to think of it, (I've never worked with FW), isn't it possible to import the FW file in PS or IA?

Comment: It is possible to open the file in Photoshop but it gets flattened : no font info.